# Reasoning behind duplicate facility values in RFC5424

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, rfc

Could someone please clarify why there are duplicate entries in RFC5424 Facility values for the following values:

1. security/authorization messages
2. clock daemon

[image]

Following is the documentation referred in this context:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424

Answer (score 0):

When looking at [4.1.1 PRI Part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164#section-4.1.1) in **RFC 3164** (which has been obsoleted by [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)), you can find "(note 1)" or "(note 2)" next to the duplicated fields - as well as some others.

```
Numerical Code            Facility
4                         security/authorization messages (note 1)
9                         clock daemon (note 2)
10                        security/authorization messages (note 1)
15                        clock daemon (note 2)
```

... with the following description below the table:

> Note 1 - Various operating systems have been found to utilize
> Facilities 4, 10, 13 and 14 for security/authorization, audit,
> and alert messages which seem to be similar.

> Note 2 - Various operating systems have been found to utilize
> both Facilities 9 and 15 for clock (cron/at) messages.